# sleected value as propertie in service in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dropdown

I have a service class with a api call that takes a value from a dropdownlist. But the value from the dropdownlist is always null. So this is the service with the api call:

ExtendedSearchService

```
 selectedValue: string;

filerByRegistration() {
    console.log('registration filter2 ');
    this.participantService
      .filterParticipantsByRegistration(1, this.selectedValue as any, moment(this.startDate).format('YYYY MM D'))
      .subscribe(filterByRegistration => {
        console.log('selected value:', this.selectedValue);
        this.filterparticipantByRegistration.emit(filterByRegistration);
      });
  }
```

And this is the component:

constructor:

```
constructor(
    private qrCodeDefinitonService: QRCodeDefinitionService,
    private echeqDefinitionService: EcheqDefinitionService,
    private extendedSearchService: ExtendedSearchService
  ) {}
```

and

the call from the service:

```
 if (this.selectedSearch === 'Registratie') {
      console.log('registration99')

      this.extendedSearchService.filerByRegistration();
    }
```

and the template:

```
 <div class="search-select searchstatus" *ngIf="selectedSearch && hasStatusOptions(selectedSearch)">
        <mat-select
          placeholder="Status"
          name="status"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
          (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
        >
          <mat-option value="">--Selecteer een status--</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of getStatusOptions(selectedSearch)" [value]="option.apiStatus">
            {{ option.status }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </div>
```

And this is the error:

```
ERROR Error: Required parameter filter was null or undefined when calling filterParticipantsByRegistration.
```

Thank you

that is just the api call:

```
public filterParticipantsByRegistration(organisationId: number, filter: 'Invited' | 'Registered', start: string, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<Array<ParticipantInfoDTO>>;
```

Very strange because I get the correct vaalue back, if I do this:

```
 searchFor() {
    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Registratie') {
      console.log('registration99', this.selectedValue);      

      this.extendedSearchService.filerByRegistration();
    }
```

```
registration99 Invited
```

But I need the selectedValue property like this:

```
 filerByRegistration(selectedValue: any) {
    console.log('registration filter2 ');
    this.participantService
      .filterParticipantsByRegistration(1, selectedValue as any, moment(this.startDate).format('YYYY MM D'))
      .subscribe(filterByRegistration => {
        console.log('selected value:', selectedValue);
        this.filterparticipantByRegistration.emit(filterByRegistration);
      });
  }
```

And I changed this:

```
   this.extendedSearchService.filerByRegistration(this.selectedValue);
```

Comment: Could you show the `filterParticipantsByRegistration` function's code?

Comment: Did you call `filerByRegistration` somewhere else?

Comment: What do you mean? Just in the extended component:   this.extendedSearchService.filerByRegistration();

Comment: The strange thing is that I put the call from the service directly in component it works. So without using the extendedService

Comment: It's obvious. In your component `this.selectedValue` has value but you didn't pass it to your service, so in the service, the property `selectedValue` was initialized as `null` by default. Just simply pass it to your service by  `this.extendedSearchService.filerByRegistration(this.selectedValue);`, you don't need `selectedValue` in your service.

Comment: updated post oe

Comment: Glad to help. I will post my comment as an answer, could you accept it?

Comment: Hi Quan, but this item is related to this item: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476385/how-to-do-cross-side-communication-between-components-and-observable

Comment: Yes, oke, but I dont see your answare, so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component `this.selectedValue` has value but you didn't pass it to your service, so in the service, the property `selectedValue` was initialized as null by default.

My solution is to pass it to your service as an argument, like

```
this.extendedSearchService.filerByRegistration(this.selectedValue);
```

You don't need the `selectedValue` in your service.